# Continuous form of verb after "provided/providing/as long as/so long as"

Tags: conjunctions

In my grammar textbook, under the section dedicated to  **provided/providing/as long as/so long as** it is stated that they act as conjunctions. So, can we use –ing clause after **provided/providing/as long as/so long as**? for example, is the following sentence grammatically correct? If not, why?

> *It takes about 20 minutes to drive to the airport provided going by taxi*.

Comment: I notice you always use the "grammar" tag. That generic tag is for people who do not know what tags to use and more experienced users will re-tag their question for them. Since you've been around for a while and you seem to know what grammar issues your questions are about, you should drop the "grammar" tag and just use the more suitable tags.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the -ing form, you need the auxiliary 'to be' with 'going' and you need the collective 'you'.

> provided you are going by taxi.
> providing you are going by taxi.  (sounds awkward with two -ing words?)
> as long as you are going by taxi.
> so long as you are going by taxi.

However, I think it sounds more natural to just use 'go'.

> It takes about 20 minutes to drive to the airport provided you go by taxi.

Or you could avoid these complications by using "it is by taxi" in all cases.

> It takes about 20 minutes to drive to the airport provided it is by taxi.